# if then statement not working asp

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, asp-classic

I've been trying every combination to make this `if then` statement work on my ASP page. I've calling fields from 2 access database, then I need to compare both to see if there is a facility that has a report against them.

At first I was using the facility name as the anchor to both database files. It worked pretty good until there was an issue with double quotes in the name. This code worked

```
 <%
          for k=0 to y-1
          if (B(1,k)) = facility then
          %>&bull;<a href="detail-e.asp?ID=<%=B(0,k)%>"><%=B(2,k)%></a><br /><%
          end if
          NEXT
          %>
```

So all I did was add a facility id number in the second database (row 12) since the ID already existed in the first database

```
      <%
      for k=0 to y-1
          response.write(ID)
          response.write("\")
          response.write(B(12,k))
      if (B(12,k)) = ID then
          response.write("TRUE")
      %>&bull;<a href="detail-e.asp?ID=<%=B(0,k)%>"><%=B(2,k)%></a><br /><%
      else
          response.write("FALSE")
      end if
          response.write("<br>")
      NEXT
      %>
```

as you can see, I've tested that the values are acually the same. The results of this `If Then` is;

> 2006225\2006225FALSE 2006225\2007101FALSE 2006225\2006225FALSE
>   2006225\2004245FALSE 2006225\279025FALSE 2006225\2006225FALSE
>   2006225\2006225FALSE 2006225\2006225FALSE 2006225\2006225FALSE

Comment: You should tag your question with an appropriate ASP tag, such as `ASP.Net`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your example code does not show how your variable named ID is assigned, my first guess would be that this may be due to variables being untyped in VBscript and you may not be assigning the type you are expecting to either the above mentioned variable or your array in the above code. You may want to use forced concatenation to make certain the evaluation is based on string types. You can concatenate an empty string in VBscript to force it to evaluate the whole expression as a string (this is what is also happening when you are writing the output). If it works this way, then most likely your variable may actually be getting assigned to a recordset field rather than a string value or something similar.

```
if ("" & B(12,k)) = ("" & ID) then
```

Comment: `if ("" & B(12,k)) = ("" & ID) then`
99% there, it's the second attempt that didn't work but you are right.
Even if I'm pulling numbers, the fields in MS Access are in plain text _type_.